# Flutter Notifications Panel

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, localnotification

I'm using with success the flutter local notification plugin. Now I'm struggling for create a page with all notifications.

Is there a way to collect all incoming local notifications of my app (even if dismissed and/or not clicked) in a list (the classic notification page like FB etc.)

I only notice that I can track the tapped notification but not only the arrival notification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unfortunately is not possible, because notifications are not stored anywhere. They exist in memory on the device, until the user dismisses them, or they are replaced with a message of a similar ID, or the OS just removes them altogether.

Your best bet, is to generate a table on your mobile backend, that will store these notifications (the same ones that will be broadcasted to the users notification center), then get the app to read directly from this table, and store it on a local SQLite database.

These notifications that are broadcasted, will need to be sent from the backend itself, with the exact same content, as that being stored on the table I mentioned. This will ensure data integrity between the notification center, and that of the app.

[**EDIT**]
Please make sure that you use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) for mobile push notifications. These are completely free, as per the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

For Tutorials, please look at these:

1. https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e
2. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-flutter-app/

Comment: I use firebase for db, so it's better if I directly use firebase notification?

Comment: yes, please use firebase notifications. Firebase notifications are also free for unlimited devices, so from a business standpoint it makes sense.

Comment: Basically the content you are posting to firebase FCM, please make sure you store it on your database. Then the app will synchronise with the database to render notifications within the app, and will also manage notifications received from firebase, via the notification center

Comment: please make sure that you do not use the legacy apis. Your backend needs to generate an access token, for the session, before expiring. This is to avoid future issues with google

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I need to study this part..do you know some similar project for example?

Comment: are you asking for source code, or an app to play with?

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/didinj/flutter-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-push-notification-example

Comment: I've provided some links for tutorials on my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: if this answer, answers your question, I'd appreciate it if you could mark it as the answer. This will help me help more people. Thanks